# Target individual product CSS style

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to target a specific product in the CSS below, so that each could have a different style colour?

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product h3, .woocommerce ul.products li.product h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title, .woocommerce ul.products li.product h2.woocommerce-loop-category__title {
color: #00F;
}
```

Site URL: https://www.elitekidscoaching.com/camp-booking/

support

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [nth-child selector](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_nth-child.asp) to accomplish this, there are many different combinations, for instance you could change the color for all the even or odd products, you could do every 4 products, etc. An example would be:

```css
ul.products li:nth-child(even) h2 {
  color:red;
}
ul.products li:nth-child(odd) h2 {
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="products columns-4">
  <li><a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's a good resource to familiarize yourself with how it works: [Useful :nth-child Recipes](https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/)

Answer (score 1):

Not much information to go on here. Are you wanting these colors to be random? Specific? Dynamically generated based on changing products?

The site as is you can easily target these specific products by doing the following:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product.post-1052 h3, 
.woocommerce ul.products li.product.post-1052 h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title,
.woocommerce ul.products li.product.post-1052 h2.woocommerce-loop-category__title {
    color: #00F;
}
```

Just change the .post-1052 to the relevant post and repeat.

You could also simplify by targetting this way:

```
li.product.post-1052 h3, 
li.product.post-1052 h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title,
li.product.post-1052 h2.woocommerce-loop-category__title {
    color: #00F;
}

li.product.post-1863 h3, 
li.product.post-1863 h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title,
li.product.post-1863 h2.woocommerce-loop-category__title {
    color: #ff0000;
}

.... Keep adding here
```

If Sass is an option for you I can point you to resources to lighten or darken colors randomly.

Comment: Absolutely spot on. Thank you very much. I experimented with the post-2221 option, but never hit on the right syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:nth-child](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_nth-child.asp) pseudo-selector to achieve what you want, like

```
.foobar:nth-child(1) {
    /*some color*/
}

.foobar:nth-child(2) {
    /*some color*/
}

.foobar:nth-child(3) {
    /*some color*/
}

.foobar:nth-child(4) {
    /*some color*/
}

.foobar:nth-child(5) {
    /*some color*/
}

.foobar:nth-child(6) {
    /*some color*/
}

.foobar:nth-child(7) {
    /*some color*/
}

/*and so on*/
```

Or, if this is not enough, you can use Javascript to go through the elements and set their color.